# Swift 3 - Send boolean to different classes

Tags: ios, swift, class

I'm trying to make an app where on the welcome screen you can either resume a game or start a new game, both would be handled in the same class. However, I'm not sure how I would send the info of weather the user pressed resume or new game, as its needed in a different class. Its also important that I can change the value in both classes. The solution I found is to use `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` However, its inside an if statement so I can't use override and I think thats what causing it to not work. Does anyone know a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Add it in UserDefaults and use that value.

Comment: You can UserDefaults or PostNotification, whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it in UserDefaults and use the value from there.

to Add/Update

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Key") //Bool
```

to Fetch/Get

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Key")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
import Foundation

class Game: NSObject, NSCoding {

    static var sharedInstance = Game(status: false)

    var status = false

    init(status: Bool) {
        super.init()
        self.status = status
    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        var status: Bool = false
        if (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "status") as? Bool) != nil {
            status = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "status") as! Bool
        }

        self.init(status: status)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(status, forKey: "status")
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var option = Game.sharedInstance.status
```

Comment: This can be used by all classes